# Testing WorkManager - RUNNING instead of ENQUEUED

Tags: integration-testing, android-testing, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, instrumented-test

I am following [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/integration-testing#periodic-work) example, but my test fails, since `workInfo.state` is `RUNNING` instead of `ENQUEUED`. Does anyone know what might be the issue? Please let me know if I should provide more code/context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but adding constraints to the request resolved the issue. It did not matter what constraints I set, it succeeded anyhow. That is, the test passed both with `NetworkType.METERED` and `NetworkType.UNMETERED`

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.METERED).build()
val request = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<EchoWorker>(15, MINUTES)
        .setInputData(input)
        .setConstraints(constraints) // added this line
        .build()
```